# What is the datatype of number in parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

i get the error when i retrieving the data from parse. the parse object has the type number

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

i am using ParseQuery to get the object

```
for(ParseObject sample:ob){
        k= (double) sample.get("time");
        l= (double) sample.get("ppm");


        lineGraph(k,l);
    }
```

Comment: you want double or int from number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a double variable then do this:

```
for(ParseObject sample:ob){
    k = sample.getDouble("time");
    l = sample.getDouble("ppm");


    lineGraph(k,l);
}
```

If you want an int variable then do this:

```
for(ParseObject sample:ob){
    int k = sample.getInt("time");
    int l = sample.getInt("ppm");


    lineGraph(k,l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to 'unbox' the integer value:

```
k = (double) sample.get("time").intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse Number into any number datatype like int,long or double.
Try this.

```
   // Parse into double
    k = (double) sample.getDouble("time").
    l = (double) sample.getDouble("ppm");
  // Parse into int
    k = (int) sample.getInt("time").
    l = (int) sample.getInt("ppm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
for (ParseObject sample : ob) {
    k = (double) ((Integer) sample.get("time").intValue();
    l = (double) ((Integer) sample.get("ppm").intValue();

    lineGraph(k,l);
}
```